# C# Asp Net Core 6 - A connection attempt failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

**Issue**

SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the peer did not properly respond after a period of time, or the established connection failed because the connected host did not respond

**scenario**

we have a main web application asp.net core 6 and sub apps with asp.net core 6. the main app communicate with the sub app. we using a SharedCookie.

on local machine all is fine. it works.

on first Server A all is fine. all application in browser available and the main app can communicate with the sub apps.

[image]

on a second Server B it works not. i only get above issue.

after using my friend Google, i often read, this issue comes random, but a real fix or workaround i'm not found.

i'm not sure, how to fix. any ideas?

**simple code**

```
    var builder = new UriBuilder(_config.GetValue<string>("SomeUrl");
    var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
    query["id"] = theId;
    builder.Query = query.ToString();

    string url = builder.ToString();

    HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new()
    {
        UseCookies = true,
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
    };

    foreach (var cookie in httpContext.Request.Cookies)
    {
        clientHandler.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Key, cookie.Value, "/", _config.GetValue<string>("ConfigValue")));
    }

    var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
    MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue contentType = new("application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);

    return await client.GetAsync(url);
```

**Edit**

A short summary:

- local machine all worked fine, no issue
- first Server, where the apps published, all worked fine, no issues
- second Server, where the apps analogue published, there ist the connection issue

Comment: Suggestion.  Try to use POSTMAN to test your rest-server.......then after you get that working....you can code your client-http-client to that.  Aka, eliminate C# http-client code when debugging..then after it works with postman..."mimic" it in C# http client code.

Comment: yeah, it's an idea to try. but it is a little cracy that all works fine on two machines (local, Server A). so i try POSTMAN.

Comment: Please use a profiler to collect more runtime data for analysis. Your code snippet exhibits a typical mistake (expensive `HttpClient` object not reused properly) so the whole project might have many other issues in this field.

Comment: I look at it this way.  If you can't get postman to work.....you'll never get "code it up" to work.    Pay attention to SSL enabled option in Postman.

Comment: Is there any difference between the first server and the second server? is there a difference in the way you publish to the two servers?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. after hours spending in this issue, i have a solution.

on the second server solved a entry in the host file the issue. now the second server worked fine, too.